# Compiling mex file from c++ wtih MATLAB R2016b, MinGW64 and mysql on Windows10

Tags: c++, mysql, matlab, windows-10, mingw-w64

I'm new to both Windows and C++, so I'm hoping someone can provide me expert knowledge on this. Apologies in advance for the super long post, but I'm trying to get all the relevant information in.

I've been given some Matlab (R2016b) and C++ code that I need to get working on a Windows laptop.  I've installed the MinGW64 compiler in Matlab, and tried to run as follows:

```
mex('<my script>', '-v', ['-I' inclib], ['-L' linklib], '-lmysqlclient')
```

Where inclib='C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include'
and linklib='C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib'

This gave me a metric tone of error messages That I don't know how to deal with.  It started with

> Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file

repeated about a million times, followed by:

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client_plugin.obj):(.text$mn+0x175):
> undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client_plugin.obj):(.text$mn+0x1cf): undefined reference to` __security_check_cookie'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client_plugin.obj):(.text$mn+0x3c2):
> undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client_plugin.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$mysql_load_plugin_v]+0x14): undefined reference to` __GSHandlerCheck'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client_plugin.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$mysql_client_plugin_init]+0x8):
> undefined reference to `__GSHandlerCheck' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client_plugin.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$??__Fmem_root@@YAXXZ]+0x8): undefined reference to` __CxxFrameHandler4'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client_plugin.obj):(.xdata[$stateUnwindMap$??__Fmem_root@@YAXXZ]+0x2):
> undefined reference to `__std_terminate' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client_plugin.obj):(.xdata[$unwind$?do_add_plugin@@YAPEAUst_mysql_client_plugin@@PEAUMYSQL@@PEAU1@PEAXHPEAD@Z]+0x10): undefined reference to` __GSHandlerCheck'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x8c):
> undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x7c): undefined reference to` __security_check_cookie'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x425):
> undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x534): undefined reference to` __security_check_cookie'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x1f6):
> undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x71e): more undefined references to` __security_check_cookie' follow
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x502):
> undefined reference to `__imp_getaddrinfo' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x556): undefined reference to` __imp_getaddrinfo'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x590):
> undefined reference to `__imp_freeaddrinfo' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x5be): undefined reference to` __imp_socket'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x5ed):
> undefined reference to `__imp_bind' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x600): undefined reference to` __imp_WSAGetLastError'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x60c):
> undefined reference to `__imp_closesocket' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x652): undefined reference to` __imp_closesocket'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x65d):
> undefined reference to `__imp_freeaddrinfo' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x670): undefined reference to` __imp_freeaddrinfo'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x6fd):
> undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x71b): undefined reference to` __imp_freeaddrinfo'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x72a):
> undefined reference to `__imp_freeaddrinfo' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x1d5): undefined reference to` __imp_WSAGetLastError'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x3f):
> undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0xfc): undefined reference to` __imp_getsockopt'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x147):
> undefined reference to `__imp_getsockopt' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x15a): undefined reference to` __imp_WSASetLastError'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x31):
> undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie' C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x87): undefined reference to` __security_check_cookie'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
> 8.0\lib/mysqlclient.lib(C:/build/sb_1-3692420-1625128314.67/release/libmysql/clientlib_objlib.dir/RelWithDebInfo/client.obj):(.text$mn+0x91):
> undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server

also repeated about a million times.  It seems that there's a library I'm missing somewhere?

The verbose output prior to the error messages looks like this:

> ... Looking for compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)' ...
> ... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset').
> ... Looking for file 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++.exe' ...Yes.
> ... Looking for folder 'C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset' ...Yes.
> Found installed compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
> Set PATH = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\include\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\simulink\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\lib\win64;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\bin\x64;C:\Users\marko\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
> Set INCLUDE = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\include;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\include;
> Set LIB = C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\lib;;C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\lib;;
> Set MW_TARGET_ARCH = win64;win64;
> Set LIBPATH = C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64;
> Options file details

---

```
Compiler location: C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset
Options file: C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\bin\win64\mexopts\mingw64_g++.xml
CMDLINE2 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -s -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def" C:\Users\marko\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\mysql.obj C:\Users\marko\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\cpp_mexapi_version.obj   -lmysqlclient  "-LC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"   -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -o mysql.mexw64
CXX : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++
COMPILER : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++
DEFINES : -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
MATLABMEX : -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE 
CXXFLAGS : -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11
INCLUDE : -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include"
CXXOPTIMFLAGS : -O -DNDEBUG
CXXDEBUGFLAGS : -g
LDXX : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++
LINKER : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++
LDFLAGS : -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined
LDTYPE : -shared
LINKEXPORT : -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mexFunction.def"
LINKEXPORTVER : -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def"
LIBLOC : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64
LINKLIBS : -lmysqlclient  "-LC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"   -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas
LDOPTIMFLAGS : -s
LDDEBUGFLAGS : -g
OBJEXT : .obj
LDEXT : .mexw64
SETENV : set COMPILER=g++ 
            set COMPFLAGS=-c -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  
            set OPTIMFLAGS=-O -DNDEBUG 
            set DEBUGFLAGS=-g 
            set LINKER=g++ 
            set LINKFLAGS=-m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -lmysqlclient -llibmysqlclient   "-LC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"   -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mexFunction.def" 
            set LINKDEBUGFLAGS=-g
            set NAME_OUTPUT= -o "%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%"
MINGWROOT : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset
MATLABROOT : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b
ARCH : win64
SRC : <myscript>;"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp"
OBJ : C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\mysql.obj;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
OBJS : C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\mysql.obj C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\cpp_mexapi_version.obj 
SRCROOT : C:\Users\<user>\<path>\mysql
DEF : C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\mysql.def
EXP : mysql.exp
LIB : mysql.lib
EXE : mysql.mexw64
ILK : mysql.ilk
MANIFEST : mysql.mexw64.manifest
TEMPNAME : mysql
EXEDIR : 
EXENAME : mysql
OPTIM : -O -DNDEBUG
LINKOPTIM : -s
CMDLINE1_0 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG C:\Users\marina\ZooScanDatabase_scripts_GUI_access_09Jun2021_R2016b\mysql.cpp -o C:\Users\marko\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\mysql.obj
CMDLINE1_1 : C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" -o C:\Users\marko\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
```

---

Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG C:\Users\marina\ZooScanDatabase_scripts_GUI_access_09Jun2021_R2016b\mysql.cpp -o C:\Users\marko\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\mysql.obj
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -c -DMX_COMPAT_32   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include"  -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/simulink/include" -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=c++11 -O -DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" -o C:\Users\marko\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2016b\3P.instrset\mingw_492.instrset\bin\g++ -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -shared -s -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def" C:\Users\marko\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\mysql.obj C:\Users\marko\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_260867394249056_12624\cpp_mexapi_version.obj   -lmysqlclient  "-LC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib"   -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2016b\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -lm -llibmwlapack -llibmwblas -o mysql.mexw64

Comment: Did you redact out “<my script>” and “<user>”?

Comment: @CrisLuengo, yes I did.

Comment: Because in the debug output I see both “C:\Users\marina” and “C:\Users\marko”, which is extremely weird. It would be good if you could describe better what you are actually doing. It is quite hard to know what is going wrong when you are behind the keyboard, it is very hard when all you have is a good description, and it is impossible when you get only a distorted description.